# Triggers / Stored Procs for Data Integrity

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, data-integrity

I have a table called Documents which stores filenames, notes etc. about documents. The relevant fields are:

- `Document_ID` - Autonumber
- `Document_Type_ID` - FK to a lookup table `Document_Types`
- `Table_Unique_ID`

The `Table_Unique_ID` relates to any of the other IDs used in other tables and we know *which* table by the relevant `Document_Type_ID`.

E.g.

- `Document_Type_ID = 1` relates to the `Projects` table, so a document record with a `Table_Unique_ID` of 1357 and `Document_Type_ID` of 1 means it relates to `Project_ID = 1357`.
- `Document_Type_ID = 2` relates to the `Sites` table, so a document record with `Table_Unique_ID` of 1357 and `Document_Type_ID` of 2 means a `Site_ID` of 1357

and so on.

This allows for great flexibility for what types of documents we hold for various record in any table, `Projects`, `Sites`, `Contacts` etc. rather than creating separate tables (`Project_Documents`, `Site_Documents` etc.).

**BUT** it's been pointed out that data integrity is harder (or impossible) to impose using traditional simple PK/FK relationships, since that 1357 could relate to either `Projects` or `Sites`.

Currently data integrity is handled by user interface checks.

The question is, can triggers or stored procedures help when inserting `Document` records or when deleting the 'other' records (`Projects`, `Contacts` etc.)?

If so, I would really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Seemingly great flexibility - but a **horrible** design from a data integrity point of view. I wouldn't waste time on investigating trigger and stuff - **fix the design!**

Comment: I agree 100% with @marc_s. The design seems "cool" but in practice it is going to be painful and slow.

Comment: *Currently data integrity is handled by user interface checks* - this makes my guts cringe..... basically, **data integrity** is ***NOT*** handled in this case....

Comment: Thank you for your honesty - I felt it might be contentious! I'll pursue more rigorous options.

Answer (score -2):

What is your primary objective? Data integrity, or flexibility and a clean design? These are conflicting interests. If you absolutely have to enforce integrity without triggers, you'll have to have an uglier design. Compromises always have to be made in database design. You'll get the data-integrity elitists harping about how bad this design is, but at the end of the day is more normalization worth it?

Comment: In most *serious* business application, data integrity is much more important than a "nice" design... after all, the data is the foundation of the solution. If you have a nice design, but your data quality is crap - you'll be out of business in no time. Don't sacrifice the all important **data integrity** for stuff like "new and trendy" designs - those come and go on a monthly basis - your data is going to be around (and important to your business) for decades. It better be **in good shape!**